# How to add tag to my form?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im creating an "advance search" like this:

[image]

and i need that when  i insert a values in the field "Ingredientes" and press the button "+", a tag is added.

For example, in the pictures i insert, "tomate" and press "+" and te tag is added, i insert "cebolla" and prees "+" and the tag is added. How i can implement this with jQuery?

Actually my html is this:

```
<div id="Form1">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> <a class="FontStyle">Palabras clave</a> </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputWord" placeholder="sofrito">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> <a class="FontStyle">Ingredientes</a> </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputWord" placeholder="tomate, cebolla, zanahoria...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out this library: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ This looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't see the javascript code where you coded your heart out trying to do this

Comment: note that you have type="email" for the inputs - probably should be type="text" and your labels do not match your input ID's and your labels include <a>'s with no href's and should probably not be <a>'s at all. And you have two forms but the same ID on the input. You should try harder to craft your code and your SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

## The goal

The concept is to **append the ingredient typed in the InputWord** (try to use a more adapted id, for best readibility & maintenability such as "IngredientName" and don't use many times the same id on the same page) **in the tags list as a tag.**

### Way to realize it :

- When do you want to append it ? => on the "plus" click
- What do you want to append ? => the ingredient name (value of the InputWord input)
- Where do you want to append it ? => at the end of tags list

### How to in jquery :

- When ?
  `$("#myPlusButtonId").click(function(){})`
- What ?
  `$("#InputWord ").val()`
- Where ?
  `$("#tagsListParentDomId").append()`

### So :

```
$("#myPlusButtonId").click(function(){
    $("#tagsListParentDomId").append($("#tagsListParentDomId").val())
})
```

ps: Also think to change the input type which is currently : "type=email".